# Where is my opcache, using fedora and installed php 5.5.8

Tags: php, fedora, opcache

Using fedora 20 and having installed php 5.5.8 the phpinfo doesn't show anything with opcache.

Added the following to php.ini

```
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

But opening a php file in my browser with phpinfo does not show me any opcache, not even the settings I added (yes I restarted httpd and changing other settings in the same file are reflected in the output of phpinfo).

Looking for `cache php` gets me:

> php-opcache.x86_64 : The Zend OPcache

Very strange because according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/opcache.installation.php) opcache can only be compiled as a shared extension.

> If you have disabled the building of default extensions with
>   --disable-all , you must compile PHP with the --enable-opcache option for OPcache to be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed php-opcache in F20 is built as shared extension:

```
[root@jupiter local]# rpm -q -l php-opcache
/etc/php-zts.d/opcache-default.blacklist
/etc/php-zts.d/opcache.ini
/etc/php.d/opcache-default.blacklist
/etc/php.d/opcache.ini
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/opcache.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so
```

I am a bit perplexed that you still modify php.ini instead of /etc/php.d - this was dish of the day for a few years. You should have opcache.ini in "Additional .ini files parsed" section of phpinfo. Given that you have modified php.ini I believe you have very old php.ini which remained in place for long time and no longer good for latest PHP.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

It looks like installing `php-opcache.x86_64` will re install all php packages. So the "normal" php binaries come with `--disable-all` flags hence installing opcache will need to install new binaries.

I'm not sure if this is correct but running

```
yum install php-opcache.x86_64
```

(note; I am using x86_64) architecture so it may be different depending on your architecture and installed fedora version 32/64 x86 version)

After that installed I now have opcache in my php.ini:

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

Comment: php-opcache does not need new binaries. It just depends on php binary.

Comment: @user3713667 yum already installed php 5.5.* but those binaries must have been compiled without opcache. installing php-opcahce.x86_64 installed all the already installed binaries.

Comment: php in F20 compiled with all extensions, then .so files are placed in relevant rpms, on load php dynamically links .so which are installed and listed in configuration. Check php.spec in SRPM.

Comment: @user3713667 It needed to download 11MB of files, seems a little big for only one extension. Working now though, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3713667 Is the pecl extension for php 5.4 not stable? When I use pecl I get: `Failed to download pecl/ZendOpcache within preferred state "stable"` Maybe I should install apc instead for 5.4?

Comment: It is fresh F20 or upgraded? It sounds like you had outdated/wrong php rpms and yum pulled newest ones for you. I just done yum install php-opcache on my up-to-date F20 and it brought only 125k download. Given your last message it may be that you php installation now is a mix of different versions

Comment: @user3713667 The FC20 is my local machine. Server is Redhat 4.4.6 Installed pecl (server has php 5.4.26) But see there is no stable for opcache: http://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache After istallig it adding version number `pecl install ZendOpcache-7.0.3` it installs but can't get it to show up in phpinfo now as well.